# When re-deploying a Kubernetes cluster, how can I keep the client certificates valid?

Tags: kubernetes, client-certificates, pki, kubeadm

We want to be able to re-deploy our Kubernetes cluster at any time, for an emergency measure when everything is screwed up, or as an easy way to upgrade to a new Kubernetes version.  We do that from scratch; in particular, /etc/kubernetes is wiped out.  But this forces us to distribute new user certificates afterwards.  However, the current ones should remain valid.

How do we do that? Store some files in /etc/kubernetes (surely not all of them) and copy them back to the cluster?  If so, which files? And copy them back before or after the `kubeadm init` call?  Or is it better to use one of the certificate-related arguments to kubeadm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep all certs in a different directory than the default directory `/etc/kubernetes/pki`.You do this before running `kubeadm init`.Now while running `kubeadm init` specify that directory by the `--cert-dir` flag or the certificatesDir field of kubeadm’s ClusterConfiguration.

Alternative option would be to skip the cert and config generation by specifying `--skip-phases=certs,kubeconfig` in `kubeadm init`.

At some point the certs will expire and you can then renew them `kubeadm alpha certs renew`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/

Comment: What about the certificates in the `.conf` files, e.g. `admin.conf`? Don’t they need to be restored as well?

Comment: .conf files does not need to change unless the ca cert was regenerated...so if you follow one of the approaches then clients using the conf files will still continue to work

Comment: All `/etc/kubernetes/*.conf` files (YAML) contain client keys and certificates. So additionall to `pki/` we should keep those as well?

Comment: yes you should keep them or skip that phase as well